# Generate report from URL - SQL Server Reporting Services 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 and when I open the following URL:

> "http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?someReport"

I'm getting report screen in which I fill my parameters and generate a report,

My question is how can I do this without any GUI? by batch file or C# script..

Thanks in advance.

=========================================================================

**EDIT:**

Thanks to all answer above I succeed to generate a report and save it as an XML using the following link:

> "http://Server/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?someReport&dFrom=01/01/2012&dTo=08/08/2012&rs%3AFormat=XML"

Thanks for you all!!!

Comment: You need to apply this to the reportserver not the reports page.  http://server/reportserver

Comment: have you tried what I posted - I am quite certain that is your issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problem is you are passing parameters to `http://server/reports...`
you need to pass parameters to `http://server/reportserver...`

I remember this issue I had when I first started using Reporting Services.

Here's the MSDN that may help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx

```
For example, to specify two parameters, “ReportMonth” and “ReportYear”, defined in a 
report, use the following URL for a native mode report server:

http://myrshost/ReportServer?/AdventureWorks 2008R2/Employee_Sales_Summary_2008R2&ReportMonth=3&ReportYear=2008
```

The result is like so:

`http://myRSServer/ReportServer/Pages/Report.aspx?%2fDefaultTenant%2fDialing+Reports%2fDialing+Agent+Performance&dFrom=01/01/2012&dTo=08/08/2012`

If you want to export the report to excel / pdf / etc you can append it:

For excel: `&rs:Format=Excel`

For PDF: `&rs:Format=PDF`

This should help as well: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1336/pass-parameters-and-options-with-a-url-in-sql-reporting-services/

Comment: what am i doing wrong with this URL:

http://win-t8o9hquvjcf/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fDatasheetforOMManual&ProjectReference=65656

It just stays blank

Comment: Your first parameter should start with a ? not a &.  Its any additional parameters need an &.

Comment: i get this if i use a ? '/DatasheetforOMManual?ProjectReference=65656' is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Your second URL option is the closest, you pass the date parameters without quotes.  As JonH states you want to use `ReportServer` instead of `Reports`, and you also want to remove `ItemPath=`

```
http://Server/ReportServer/Pages/Report.aspx?%2fDefaultTenant%2fDialing+Reports%2fDialing+Agent+Performance&dFrom=01/01/2012&dTo=08/08/2012
```

Additionaly, if you want to export the file you can append `&rs:command=render&rs:format=PDF` replacing PDF with the format you desire

Answer (score 0):

```
string URL = "YourReportUrl";     
string FullURL = URL + "&JobId=" + JobId.ToString() + "&JobNumber=" + JobNo.ToString() + "&rs%3aCommand=Render";
```

Where `JobId` and `JobNumber` will be your Parameter names.
This will directly open in your report Viewer.

To display in XML format, add this **`&rs%3AFormat=XML`** to end of URL.

```
string FullURL = URL + "&JobId=" + JobId.ToString() + "&JobNumber=" + JobNo.ToString() + "&rs%3aCommand=Render&rs%3AFormat=XML";
```

Comment: Try without quotes with your First option. Also refer this link for more info on Date parameter stuff - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155064

Comment: @HarshaHerle that link shows how to pass language not anything about dates.  I believe the issue has to do with passing the parameters to an incorrect URL.  You cannot pass the parameters to the standard GUI, you have to pass them to the `reportserver` see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following is an example for using URL for a report. It passes parameters and also specify whether the parameters should be hidden or not

```
http://myServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/InventoryTracking/Receiving/InboundContainerID
&rs:Command=Render&rc:Parameters=false&Plant="20"
```

If are using HTML file to display this, then use

```
window.location.href = url;
```