# Report Access Issue in SSRS 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

We have hundreds of SSRS 2005 reports in an ASP.Net 2.0 application. We are using following Javascript for rendering the report

```
   window.location.href = url;
```

Url Example

```
http://aaa88/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/InventoryTracking/Receiving/MyReport&rs:Command=Render&rc:Parameters=false&Emp="20"
```

Example: [Generate report from URL - SQL Server Reporting Services 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846037/generate-report-from-url-sql-server-reporting-services-2008/23113249#23113249)

By typing the url anybody in the domain is able to view the report.

We need to ensure that the report should not be accessible without entering proper credentials.

We must also ensure that the website is able to render the report using "window.location.href" and without prompting the user

What is the solution for this in SSRS 2005?

Comment: Your title states SSRS 2005, the example you provided is for SSRS 2008, then you tagged the question with SSRS-2008...which version are you using?

Comment: @ShawnMelton I am using 2005